# How to extract specific number from a ArrayList?

Tags: java, tdd

I wrote a program that will fetch text data from http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip.txt, and extract X, where X is the value next to "unixtime". This is what I got so far.

```
public class GetDataService implements DataService{
  @Override
  public ArrayList<String> getData()  {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
    URL url = new URL("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      String a = line;
      lines.add(a);
      }
      bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Can not making the request to the URL.");
    }
    return lines;
  }

public interface DataService {
  ArrayList<String> getData() throws IOException;
}

public class UnixTimeExtractor {
  private GetDataService getDataService;

  public String unixTimeExtractor()  {
    ArrayList<String> lines = getDataService.getData();
//how to extract the value next to "unixtime"
```

I don't know how to extract value next to "unixtime". And how can I test NetWork Error for GetDataService Class.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to extract value next to "unixtime".

To extract values from a list, you can iterate over the list,
do some check on each value as needed,
and return the value when you found a match, for example:

```
for (String line : lines) {
  if (line.startsWith("unixtime: ")) {
    return line;
  }
}
```

To extract the value that comes after "unixtime: " in a string, you could use several strategies:

- `line.substring("unixtime: ".length())`
- `line.replaceAll("^unixtime: ", "")`
- `line.split(": ")[1]`
- ...

Btw do you really need the list of lines?
If not, then you can save memory and reduce input processing if you perform this check while reading the input stream from the URL,
and stop reading immediately after you found just what you needed.

> And how can I test NetWork Error for GetDataService Class.

To test that network errors are handled correctly,
you would need to make the parts of code that can throw network errors injectable.
Then in your test cases you could inject replacement code that will throw exception,
and verify that the program handles the exceptions correctly.

One technique is "extract and extend".
That is, extract the `url.openStream()` call to a dedicated method:

```
InputStream getInputStream(URL url) throws IOException {
  return url.openStream();
}
```

And replace in your code `url.openStream()` with a call to `getInputStream(url)`.
Then in your test method, you can override this method with throwing an exception,
and verify what happens. Using fluent assertions with AssertJ:

```
  @Test
  public void test_unixtime() {
    UnixTimeExtractor extractor = new UnixTimeExtractor() {
      @Override
      InputStream getInputStream(URL url) throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
      }
    };
    assertThatThrownBy(extractor::unixtime)
      .isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
      .hasMessage("Error while reading from stream");
  }
```

You could do similarly for reading from the input stream.

Comment: @MinhQuangNgo The test could be implemented using Mockito. If you have difficulty making it work, you should ask a separate question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over ArrayList using `indexOf` and get the next value

```
public String unixTimeExtractor() {
    List<String> lines = getDataService.getData();

    int i = lines.indexOf(unixTime);

    if (i != -1 && ++i < lines.size()) {
        return lines.get(i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use java-8 to achieve the same. Change your method to the following :

```
public String unixTimeExtractor() {
   ArrayList<String> lines = getDataService.getData();
   return lines.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("unixtime"))
               .map(s -> s.substring("unixtime: ".length()))
               .findFirst()
               .orElse("Not found");
}
```

Here we stream over the list `lines` to check if the *String* `unixtime` is found. If it is found then we return its value using sub-string else we return `Not found`.

For the test case you can refer to janos' answer.